# How to Shade a Region Between Two Curves on a Graph in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have two functions representing Marginal Abatement Cost (MAC) and Marginal Damage Cost (MD) as follows:

```py
def MAC(E):
    return 750 - E

def MD(E):
    return 0.5 * E
```

I want to create a graph that shows both the MAC and MD curves on the same plot. Additionally, I would like to shade the region between the two curves where the MAC is higher than 0 in cost but lower than 250, and the emission level (E) varies between 0 and approximately 750.

I have tried using the `fill_between` function from Matplotlib, but the shading is not displaying as expected. How can I properly shade this region between the MAC and MD curves on the graph?

Code Sample:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def MAC(E):
    return 750 - E

def MD(E):
    return 0.5 * E

# Generate values for E from 0 to 1000
E_values = np.linspace(0, 1000, 100)

# Calculate MAC and MD values for each E value
MAC_values = MAC(E_values)
MD_values = MD(E_values)

# Plot MAC and MD on the same graph
plt.plot(E_values, MAC_values, label='MAC', color='blue')
plt.plot(E_values, MD_values, label='MD', color='red')

# Add labels and a legend
plt.xlabel('Emission Level (E)')
plt.ylabel('Cost')
plt.legend()

# Add a title to the graph
plt.title('Marginal Abatement Cost (MAC) and Marginal Damage Cost (MD)')

# Shade the region between MAC and MD curves where MAC is higher than 0 and lower than 250
plt.fill_between(E_values, MAC_values, MD_values, where=(MAC_values >= 0) & (MAC_values <= 250), color='lightblue', alpha=0.5)

# Show the graph
plt.grid(True)
plt.axhline(0, color='black', linewidth=0.5)
plt.axvline(0, color='black', linewidth=0.5)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

**Expected Output:**

The code should produce a graph with two curves for MAC and MD, and the region between the two curves where the MAC is higher than 0 in cost but lower than 250 should be shaded in light blue. The emission level (E) should vary between 0 and approximately 750 on the x-axis. The blue-circled region is where I want to shade:

[image]

Comment: Posting good / bad graph images would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because the `where` argument is only used to limit the left-right extents.

For the `fill_between`, the top is bounded by the smallest of `MAC_values`, `MD_values`, or 250. To do that comparison, you can use `np.minimum.reduce`, which will perform element-wise comparisons for all the arrays (equivalent to stacking them and performing the min across one of the axes).

```py
top = np.minimum.reduce([MAC_values,
                         MD_values,
                         np.ones_like(MAC_values)*250])
# equivalent
# top = np.min(np.stack([MAC_values,
#                        MD_values,
#                        np.ones_like(MAC_values), axis=0)
plt.fill_between(x=E_values, y1=top, y2=0, 
                 where=(E_values >= 0) & (E_values <= 750),
                 color='lightblue', alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

Note: In this case, you could have gotten away with just considering `MAC_values` and `MD_values` since within the range of acceptable `E_values` they don't go above 250, but I gave you code for a more general problem. If this condition will always be true, you can just do:

```py
top = np.minimum(MAC_values, MD_values)
```

or, equivalently:

```py
top = np.stack([MAC_values, MD_values], axis=0)
```

Update: simplified the code by making use of the `where` argument as intended.

Comment: @Bosser445 I just updated the code to be simpler by making use of the `where` argument. I'm not sure why I didn't use it when I first answered your question.

Comment: thanks a lot, I appreciate the extended help